# Set specific path for assetPath GaussianBlurBackgroundProcessor (Twilio) - reactj

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, twilio

I'm trying to implement a Twilio background blur, using the GaussianBlurBackgroundProcessor. You can check the docs [here](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-video-processors.js/classes/gaussianblurbackgroundprocessor.html).

I need to find a way to set a path for a folder but for a specific reason, I don't want to use the public react folder.

I tried to use the `CopyWebpackPlugin` to copy the files for the build folder and did work but when I tried to run the application using the development start script the files are not available.

Do you have any clue how can I set the assetPath without using the public folder and add the specific folder to the bundle?

assetPath - https://twilio.github.io/twilio-video-processors.js/interfaces/gaussianblurbackgroundprocessoroptions.html#assetspath

`CopyWebpackPlugin`

```
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: "node_modules/@twilio/video-processors/dist/build",
          to: "static/blur",
          noErrorOnMissing: false
        },
      ],
    })
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you not want the folder to be the `public` folder? Can you share the config you used with the `CopyWebpackPlugin`?

Comment: Thanks, @philnash. The team doesn't want to put the files inside the public folder but they didn't get me a good reason. I used the public folder and worked well...but now I'm trying to see if we can use without the public folder.

Comment: The files need to be public so that they can be loaded from the front end. It genuinely makes no sense to have them anywhere else, unless it is also a publicly available directory too.